# Eclispe start server success,but in Tomcat's Webapps cannot find the project

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, tomcat7

I want to using the Tomcat 7.0 and Eclipse 4.X to do some coding, and am having some trouble.  When I add the project into tomcat, it starts successfully however I find that Tomcat's Web apps show nothing even about the project which I just launched.

When I input URL in a browser to visit it, the page appears to be running ok.

I am extremely sure that the Tomcat Path configuration has no problems. it Windows->preferences->Tomcat(sitting the Tomcae home and Configuration file,Tomcat home as your tomcat installation path)

Now I want to see all the project which I launched in tomcat's Web apps, How can I configure Eclipse or Tomcat to resolve this?

Comment: All: this problem has solved.Eclipse cannot suppports that add the project into Tomcat automaticly, if you want to achieve this function,your should make a configuration about that:Server->Overview->Server Locations(choose Use Tomcat installation(takes control of tomcat installation), then setting the Deploy path as your own webapps path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't see the Project what you have created , you cannot see if you didn't give the correct **tomcat**  path ,

Actually when the eclipse is getting started its usually ask path , in that whatever folder you select, the project will be deployed there,

Tomcat is a server only eclipse adding it to run the project, other than that it has **no connection** between **eclipse** and **tomcat**.

If you want to deploy your project with tomcat **web apps** you can go with **command prompt** itself.

Comment: I am extremely sure that the Tomcat Path configuration has no problems.it Windows->preferences->Tomcat(sitting the Tomcae home and Configuration file,Tomcat home as your tomcat installation path)

Comment: @huang you are using tomcat exe or zip , and while commenting make sure that your answer spell is correct